# Error whilst indexing price + products

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, indexing

The error started when I made the switch to flat catalogues. Exception 1:

```
2018-02-07T01:14:41+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1, query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_price` (`entity_id`, `customer_group_id`, `website_id`, `tax_class_id`, `price`, `final_price`, `min_price`, `max_price`, `tier_price`, `group_price`, `status`) SELECT `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`entity_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`customer_group_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tax_class_id`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`price`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`final_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`min_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`max_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`tier_price`, `catalog_product_index_price_idx`.`group_price` FROM `catalog_product_index_price_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `entity_id` = VALUES(`entity_id`), `customer_group_id` = VALUES(`customer_group_id`), `website_id` = VALUES(`website_id`), `tax_class_id` = VALUES(`tax_class_id`), `price` = VALUES(`price`), `final_price` = VALUES(`final_price`), `min_price` = VALUES(`min_price`), `max_price` = VALUES(`max_price`), `tier_price` = VALUES(`tier_price`), `group_price` = VALUES(`group_price`), `status` = VALUES(`status`)
Trace: #0 /home/neckan6/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/neckan6/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/neckan6/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/neckan6/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#7 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_product...', Array, false)
#8 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_product...', 'catalog_product...', false)
#9 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Price.php(388): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#11 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#15 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#16 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/neckan6/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Exception 2:

```
2018-02-07T01:14:42+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Exception' with message 'No content found in files:
/home/neckan6/public_html/js/widget/widgetadmin.js' in /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php:750
Stack trace:
#0 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(727): Mage_Core_Helper_Data->mergeFiles(Array, '/home/neckan6/p...', false, NULL, 'js')
#1 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Design/Package.php(641): Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->_mergeFiles(Array, '/home/neckan6/p...', false, NULL, 'js')
#2 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package->getMergedJsUrl(Array)
#3 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php(276): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#4 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php(214): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->_prepareStaticAndSkinElements('<script type="t...', Array, Array, Array)
#5 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page/head.phtml(14): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->getCssJsHtml()
#6 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/neckan6/p...')
#7 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#8 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#9 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#10 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#11 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('head', true)
#12 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('head')
#13 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home/neckan6/p...')
#14 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#15 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#18 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#20 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(55): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#21 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->listAction()
#22 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('list')
#23 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#24 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#25 /home/neckan6/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#26 /home/neckan6/public_html/index.php(91): Mage::run('', 'store')
#27 {main}
```

Comment: Add more details

Comment: Have you use the flat mode for category and product as in catalog admin configuration?